# Conditional formatting fill pattern

Tags: microsoft-excel, conditional-formatting

I have a query around the auto-population or conditionally formatted cells. Example below:

[image]

As it stands, the amount column J has the formula `=IF(ISBLANK(H9)+ISBLANK(I9)=2,"",H9-I9)`.

The entire column has conditional formatting: if the value in the cell is greater than 0 to format with green fill and dark green text. If the value is less than 0 to format with light red fill with dark red text.

For some reason, as in the image, when no data is entered into any cell, other than the above formula for its representative line it auto-fills to green.

How do I adjust the formatting so that there is no fill until the value of the cell is either greater than or less than 0?

[image: Conditional formatting rule set-up example]

Comment: How exactly you set up your conditional formatting? Please post screenshot of that too.

Comment: I have added to the original posting

Answer (score 0):

For a quick and dirty solution: Make a new conditional formatting rule with `=""` in the EQUAL TO box.

[image]

---

Make sure that this rule is at the top of all the rules, like this

[image]

Not like this:

[image]

Comment: @Max are you comfortable with conditional formatting with custom formula's?